# Can we batch multiple onCreate events in one cloud function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function `newMessage` to listen on any onCreate() event in firebase realtime database. When the `newMessage` function is triggered, it will get the snapshot of the message content, and use mailgun to send email notification for the new message.
pseudo code is like:

```
exports.newMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/privateMessages/{userA}/{userB}/{messageId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    let senderEmail, receiverEmail, messageContent;
    // 1. get message senderEmail, receiverEmail and messageContent from the snap and context.

    // 2. use mailgun to send email to receiverEmail for the new message
    let data = {
      from: senderEmail,
      to: receiverEmail,
      subject: 'New Message from Freebies',
      text: messageContent
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
      console.log(body);
    });
  })

  return null;
})
```

My concern is if user is flooding the chat messages, from the `newMessage`, it will send email every time there comes a new message. On receiver's side, it would be annoying if there are too many email notifications in the inbox. So my question is that is it possible to have multiple onCreate() to get multiple new messages, say within 1 hour, and send only 1 email message for those new messages?

Comment: Just use a timestamp or counter field to validate if the user already has new messages in his inbox.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer Can you elaborate a bit more on your comments? Where should the timestamp or the counter be put? Inside the onCreate()? If so, next time when onCreate() is triggered, would it be able to get the previous counter? Can the timestamp or the counter to be a global accessed value? Thanks!

Comment: You can make use of global variables in Cloud Functions to help you regarding that. Continuing with the solution that @ConstantinBeer provided, here you have a [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#functions-tips-scopes-nodejs) from the documentation where you have an example of using global variables. This way you should be able to implement a counter to avoid the spam of emails.

Comment: Thank you @bhito. I will try it out.

Comment: You're welcome! If that works for you, please post your solution as an answer so other people can see it in the future @damingzi